# Parsing JSON without keys in SWIFT

Tags: swift

Using this code to get and parse:

```
func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData
{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest))
}
func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> NSDictionary
{
    var error: NSError?
    var boardsDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
    return boardsDictionary
}
    var parsedJSON = parseJSON(getJSON("url"))
```

`println(parsedJSON)` result:

```
{
message = "";
result =     (
            {
        BC = B;
        BCL = Bbb;
        C = "2014-02-13T00:00:00";
        IA = 1;
        MC = L;
        MCL = Lll;
        MN = "B-L";
        MS = "165";
    },
            {
        BC = B;
        BCL = Bbb;
        C = "2014-02-13T00:00:00";
        IA = 1;
        MC = E;
        MCL = Eee;
        MN = "B-E";
        MS = "654";
    },
            {
        BC = B;
        BCL = Bbb;
        C = "2014-02-13T00:00:00";
        IA = 1;
        MC = D;
        MCL = Ddd;
        MN = "B-D";
        MS = "864";
    },
);
success = 1;
}
```

`println(parsedJSON["result"])` result:

```
    {
        BC = B;
        BCL = Bbb;
        C = "2014-02-13T00:00:00";
        IA = 1;
        MC = L;
        MCL = Lll;
        MN = "B-L";
        MS = "165";
    },
            {
        BC = B;
        BCL = Bbb;
        C = "2014-02-13T00:00:00";
        IA = 1;
        MC = E;
        MCL = Eee;
        MN = "B-E";
        MS = "654";
    },
            {
        BC = B;
        BCL = Bbb;
        C = "2014-02-13T00:00:00";
        IA = 1;
        MC = D;
        MCL = Ddd;
        MN = "B-D";
        MS = "864";
    },
```

`println(parsedJSONlS["result"]!["MCL"])` gives "nil"

How can I extract MCL value from every set? Can I access values by index?

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes.  "Result" is an array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like parsedJSONlS["result"] will give you an array of dictionaries.  You can do something like:

```
var array = parsedJSONlS["result"]
array[0]["MCL"]
// or
var dictionary = array[0] as Dictionary
println(dictionary["MCL"])
```

This is of course only to give you an idea of the structure, you will have to create a loop for that array and grab all the dictionaries and extract their values.

Answer (score 0):

You should take into consideration optionals here: retrieving a value from a dictionary might return nil. So taking out every MCL value from your dictionaries and putting them on array of tuples with their index:

```
    func retrieveMCL(index : Int, value : Dictionary<String, String>) -> (Int,String)?
    {
        switch value["MCL"] {
        case .Some(let mclValue): return (index, mclValue)
        default: return nil
        }
    }

    // This mimics your results from JSON
    let results = ["result":[["MCL":"Eee"],["MCL":"Ddd"]]]
    var mclArray : Array<(Int,String)> = []

    if let resultsArray = results["result"]
    {
        for (index,value) in enumerate(resultsArray){
            if let mclTupple = retrieveMCL(index, value) {
                mclArray += mclTupple
            }
        }
    }
```